# fastText installation failed

Tags: python, anaconda

I have tried to install fastText through this by using anaconda prompt
conda install -c conda-forge fasttext
but I failed and the following message appears

(base) C:\Users\MAB>conda install -c conda-forge fasttext
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

- fasttext

Current channels:

- https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
- https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

```
https://anaconda.org
```

and use the search bar at the top of the page.

Can any one help me in installation of fastText

Comment: According to https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/fasttext, it does not have Windows supported.  This one seems to support Windows (I am not sure if this is something you want, though): https://anaconda.org/esri/fasttext

Comment: You may be able to find hints on their github page too.  https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/issues?q=windows

Answer (score 4):

As per the official site (https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/fasttext) one of the below three command can be used to install fasttext. I suppose you have only tried the first one, if that is not working, can you also try the others:

```
conda install -c conda-forge fasttext
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 fasttext
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf202003 fasttext
```

If none of the above works, the other options are to use `pip` or `build it from source`.

For `pip` use the following command:

For windows:

```
pip install fasttext_win
```

For others:

```
pip install fasttext
```

**Please note:**

As per fastText documentation(
https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/python-module.html), it seems that FastText is only builds on modern Mac OS and Linux distributions. So if none of the above command works, you may have to try building it from source.

Comment: I have followed this website to install fasttext in windows

Comment: https://medium.com/@oleg.tarasov/building-fasttext-python-wrapper-from-source-under-windows-68e693a68cbb.. but still its not working when I run code related to fasttext on anaconda jupytor notebook

Comment: is there any specific error you get or is it not able to find the module ?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on mac not sure on windows

```
pip install wheel setuptools pip --upgrade
pip3 install wheel setuptools pip --upgrade
```